# T-SQL where clause case statement

Tags: t-sql, case, where-clause

Need some small help with some SQL. I am using a `VARCHAR` value to determine in a case which logic to use in WHERE clause but I am having some issues writing this case statement.

```
where 
   (CASE WHEN @p_flag = 'ATA' 
            THEN (@p_start_ata IS NULL AND @p_end_ata IS NULL) OR (vso.poa_ata between @p_start_ata and @p_end_ata)
         ELSE (@p_start_atd IS NULL AND @p_end_atd IS NULL) OR (vso.pol_atd between @p_start_atd and @p_end_atd)
)
```

> Line 93 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'.

Its probably a minor error but its frustrating me. Maybe there is a better way of writing this? Thanks!

Comment: The CASE statement can only provide **values** - not entire code blocks. You need to rearrange your logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like said before you can not use a case statement like you are doing it. So this might be a suggestion:

```
WHERE 
    (
        @p_flag = 'ATA'
        AND 
            (
                (@p_start_ata IS NULL AND @p_end_ata)
                OR (vso.poa_ata between @p_start_ata and @p_end_ata)
            )
    )
    OR
    (
        NOT @p_flag = 'ATA'
        AND 
            (
                (@p_start_atd IS NULL AND @p_end_atd IS NULL)
                OR (vso.pol_atd between @p_start_atd and @p_end_atd)
            )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks I ended up using this. I was looking for a boolean condition which would execute one or the other block of sql but wasn't sure how to go about writing it in the where clause. This helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `CASE` like that!

It's use to get values and not restrictions. [Check this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) to view how to properly use `CASE`.

---

In your case you've to change your logic probably using `IF`'s and making the wanted `SELECT`'s.